# Django making field related to other field (object) value

Tags: django, django-models

few years ego I worked with Odoo framework. and Odoo has very nice feature like this:

```
partner_id = field.Many2one(Partner)
partner_name = fields.Char(string='Partner name', related='partner_id.name')
```

basically whenever you would assign different partner_id from Partner table, partner_name would be assigned automatically. Now I started to work with django (absolute newbie), and I can't seem to find a similar functionality. 
My question is what could be possible solution for this problem. Maybe there are already established external libraries that has this sort of functionality? 
Expected result:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
product_color = models.CharField(string='Partner name', related='product.color')
```

having in mind that product object would have color field and it would be assigned to product_color whenever product field value Product object  color value changes. Also what about storing it to database? Would be nice if there was an option to chose between storing it in database or getting it on the fly.

Cheers!

Comment: This is not supported (at least not without extra libraries). Usually one uses an `@property`, or an annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe some libraries comes to mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating data, is usually a (more severe) *antipattern*. Synchronizing data, even in two tables in the same database, often turns out harder than one might expect. Even if you would use Django's signal framework for example, then some Django ORM calls can circumvent that (for example [**`.update(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update)). But even if you somehow would cover those cases, then another program that talks to the database could update one of the two fields.

Most databases have *triggers* that can help. But again, the number of cases to cover are often larger than expected. For example, if the `Product` that we refer to is removed, then or the foreign key now points to a different `Product`, then we will need to update that field.

Therefore it is often better, to fetch the name of the related product when we need it. We can do so by (a) defining a property; or (b) make an annotation, for example in the manager.

## Defining a property

We can define a property that will load the related product, and fetch the related name, like:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def product_name(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Then we can fetch the product name with `some_order.product_name`. This might not be very efficient if we need to fetch it often, since the relations are, by default, loaded lazily in Django, and thus can result in an *N+1 problem*.

## Annotate the queryset

We can make an annotation that will fetch the name of the product in the same query when we fetch the `Order`, for example:

```
from django.db.models import F

class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            product_name=F('product__name')
        )

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    objects = OrderManager()
```

Then if we fetch an order. For example with `Order.objects.get(pk=1)`, then that `Order` object will have an attribute `product_name` with the name of the `product`.

Comment: Thank you for very informative answer. I really like the "Annotate the queryset" part which is something different that I found everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a getter is pretty easy, because you can simply have functions in a Python object behave as a property:

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

    @property
    def product_color(self):
         return self.product.color
```

This does retrieve the property on the fly, which will cause a call to the database.